# Can I specify a Stored Procedure in my LinqDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, listview

I have a Listview that I want to read the results of a Stored procedure. I have created the DBML object with the table and the stored procedure. When I configure my LinqDataSource on the page I cannot specify the SProc - only the Table. Or do I need to do it in the Listview ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom expression. See section "Using the  Selecting Event"

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx